# Running a Minecraft server I get and java arrayOutofBounds how do I fix this?

Tags: java, server, minecraft-forge

Here is the error code:

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Would you like a cupcake?

Time: 9/28/16 9:44 AM
Description: Ticking entity

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
at buildcraft.silicon.BlockLaser.func_149743_a(BlockLaser.java:84)
at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72945_a(World.java:1437)
at cofh.asmhooks.HooksCore.getEntityCollisionBoxes(HooksCore.java:118)
at net.minecraft.entity.Entity.func_70091_d(Entity.java:596)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70612_e(EntityLivingBase.java:1490)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70636_d(EntityLivingBase.java:1814)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving.func_70636_d(EntityLiving.java:367)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityAgeable.func_70636_d(SourceFile:95)
at net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityAnimal.func_70636_d(SourceFile:37)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70071_h_(EntityLivingBase.java:1611)
at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving.func_70071_h_(EntityLiving.java:206)
at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72866_a(World.java:2070)
at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72866_a(WorldServer.java:648)
at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72870_g(World.java:2034)
at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72939_s(World.java:1887)
at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72939_s(WorldServer.java:489)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71190_q(MinecraftServer.java:636)
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71190_q(DedicatedServer.java:334)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:547)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:427)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$2.run(MinecraftServer.java:685)
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at buildcraft.silicon.BlockLaser.func_149743_a(BlockLaser.java:84)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72945_a(World.java:1437)
    at cofh.asmhooks.HooksCore.getEntityCollisionBoxes(HooksCore.java:118)
    at net.minecraft.entity.Entity.func_70091_d(Entity.java:596)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70612_e(EntityLivingBase.java:1490)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70636_d(EntityLivingBase.java:1814)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving.func_70636_d(EntityLiving.java:367)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityAgeable.func_70636_d(SourceFile:95)
    at net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityAnimal.func_70636_d(SourceFile:37)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase.func_70071_h_(EntityLivingBase.java:1611)
    at net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving.func_70071_h_(EntityLiving.java:206)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72866_a(World.java:2070)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72866_a(WorldServer.java:648)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72870_g(World.java:2034)

-- Entity being ticked --
Details:
    Entity Type: Cow (net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityCow)
    Entity ID: 23
    Entity Name: Cow
    Entity's Exact location: -87.50, 65.00, 314.89
    Entity's Block location: World: (-88,65,314), Chunk: (at 8,4,10 in -6,19; contains blocks -96,0,304 to -81,255,319), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
    Entity's Momentum: -0.08, -0.08, -0.03
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72939_s(World.java:1887)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72939_s(WorldServer.java:489)
```

I have proceed with deletion of the animals but what happens is the world gets corrupted.

Comment: There's almost certainly a duplicate on [gaming.se].

Comment: Do you have a direct link by chance to the page where the question was being asked?

Answer (score 1):

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption

means that you tried to access a position in an array which doesn't exist. Note that the position always starts at 0.

E.g.

```
int[] number = new int[5];

System.out.println(number[4]);
System.out.println(number[5]); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: This makes sense I just don't know how I could go about fixing the problem. It seems to happen a lot with one of my servers but the others run perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you write the application that cause this exception? If not then you're definetly wrong here, pal. Stackoverflow is a site for devs. Go and check out the minecraft forum. There you'll have a  bigger chance of getting help with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the BuildCraft mod and specifically with the laser block within it. You need to report this issue to the BuildCraft developer at https://github.com/BuildCraft/BuildCraft/issues